# Is my Oauth right?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth

I have had Oauth on my extension for about a month now and To be completely honest, I have no idea what is going on. I try to look at statistics from google API, but there arent any.

SO my question is:

Is there something wrong with my code? And what am I doing wrong with "TRIAL_PERIOD_DAYS"?

```
 chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
    interactive: true
}, function(token){

var CWS_LICENSE_API_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/userlicenses/fcjhennclbpgegahkbbnndbhmlhkdabe';
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', CWS_LICENSE_API_URL + chrome.runtime.id);
req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
    var license = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    console.log(license);
    verifyAndSaveLicense(license);
  }
}
req.send(); 
console.log(TRIAL_PERIOD_DAYS);
var licenseStatus;
if (license.result && license.accessLevel == "FULL") {
  console.log("Fully paid & properly licensed.");
  licenseStatus = "FULL";
} else if (license.result && license.accessLevel == "FREE_TRIAL") {
  var daysAgoLicenseIssued = Date.now() - parseInt(license.createdTime, 10);
  daysAgoLicenseIssued = daysAgoLicenseIssued / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
  if (daysAgoLicenseIssued <= TRIAL_PERIOD_DAYS) {
    console.log("Free trial, still within trial period");
    licenseStatus = "FREE_TRIAL";
  } else {
    console.log("Free trial, trial period expired.");
    licenseStatus = "FREE_TRIAL_EXPIRED";
    window.open('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/premium-roulette/fcjhennclbpgegahkbbnndbhmlhkdabe');
  }
} else {
  console.log("No license ever issued.");
  licenseStatus = "NONE";
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the [Tutorial: OAuth](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth) guide for Chrome. For actual code samples check this:

1. [oauth_contacts](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/extensions/oauth_contacts/) demo.
2. [gdocs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/extensions/gdocs/) demo.

Also check the [subscription guide](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/money#subscription). It mentions a way of [verifying payment and offering free trial](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#verifying-payment) which might help in your situation.

Comment: I just realized that the problem was that I didnt set a "TRIAL_PERIOD_DAYS".